# .htaccess RewriteRule using @ sign?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-routing

I am trying to have a URL that would look like:

> mysite.com/@username

Which would route to something like:

> subdomain.mysite.com/user/@username

I'm terrible with RewriteRules and have been struggling to try to get this to work. Some of the things I have tried are:

```
RewriteRule subdomain.mysite.com/user/(.*) mysite.com/$1  [R=302,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.@)(.*) subdomain.mysite.com/user/$1  [R=302,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.@)([A-Za-z0-9_]+) mysite.com/user/$1  [R=302,NC]
```

I realize those probably make absolutely no sense. Every time I try to get my head around how the routing works, I get turned around and start writing crap like you see above.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's not **supposed** to work, I don't think.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not allowed to route to a subdomain...or the @ sign can't be used?

Comment: The @ sign should be percent escaped, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't route to a subdomain (using htaccess anyway) but you can redirect there.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule @(.*) http://subdomain.mysite.com/user/@$1 [L,R=301]
```

The @ symbol should be okay https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/763468

Comment: Great! I had actually just figured out an alternative way of doing it that was working, but I like yours better: ([@A-Za-z0-9_]+) http://subdomain.mysite.com/user/$1  [R=302,NC,L]